# DynamoDB: Check if any item matches query efficiently

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Is it possible to perform a query on a DynamoDB table using an LSI partition and sort key to check if any item matches, in such a way that it costs significantly less than a query to return all of the records that match the partition and sort key or to return the count of matching items?

Example:
A table called Colors has the LSI partition key PrimaryColor and sort key Secondary Color. I'd like to query the Colors table to find out if any records have the PrimaryColor = "blue" and SecondaryColor = "light".  I only want to know if any Colors match that query. I do not need to know the count or get the record contents.

Motivation for asking question:
From reading DynamoDB documentation and Q&A sites, it appears that it may cost the same to perform an existence check using a sort key as it does to return all of the items. I have a need to perform an existence check up to 20,000 times where each query could return 100,000 records and do not want to pay the cost of query to return all of the records for every query. If I can pay a cheaper cost by structuring the query so that it stops after finding one record that would be preferable, for example.

Answer (score 0):

On a table, a given Partition and Sort key make up the Primary key. In DynamoDB the Primary key must be unique.

So for your use-case you can do a `GetItem` and only need to access that 1 item which is efficient, if it doesn't exist you will pay the minimum amount which is 0.5 RCU.

Comment: Good point. The query would actually use an LSI, so there can be multiple records that match a given partition and sort key for a query. Could you answer for that case?

Comment: Use Query, specify the partition and sort key, and set `Limit=1`